# how to return the wordpress path to the new site

Tags: installation

Please how do i return to the default path something like this after working on the wordpress installation

```
  http://fittergroup.com/blog/   to  http://fittergroup.com/
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? "Return" how and where?

Comment: please i want to blog folder where all the content are back to the main path like this http://fittergroup.com/ so that when it is typed it will not be  http://fittergroup.com/blog/  but all i am getting is that wp-login is returning back to /blog/wp-login.pgp

Comment: Sorry. This question is still not clear, even with the comment (which actually seems to introduce addition complications). Please [edit] the question with all of the relevant information.

Comment: Are you saying you setup a multisite and now your blogs all have /blog/ on the front of their URLs, and you want to know how to undo this?

Comment: yes Tom J Nowell that is what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have read this correctly... If you want to have your url as fittergroup.com but leave all your files in fittergroup.com/blog take a look at the Wordpress documentation on '[Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)'

In your 'General' settings panel:

> In the box for WordPress address (URL): change the address to the new
>   location of your main WordPress core files. Example:
>   http://example.com/wordpress
>
> In the box for Site address (URL): change the address to the root
>   directory's URL. Example: http:// example.com

Comment: well what i did was to copy the content of the /blog to the root folder and drop it there well it is working now thank gues.